# For Jehovah's Witnesses, what are the ingredients to the bread and the wine?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, communion

I am wondering what ingredients do the Jehovah's Witnesses use in the bread and the wine. I talked to one of my friends who is a active member of the Jehovah's Witness religion but was not satisfied with her answer.

Comment: Check out Exodus, chapter 12 I think. It just calls it "unleavened bread." I don't think the recipe is available in the Christian bible, but maybe Jewish literature has more information - I'll leave the actual answer to someone who is sure. Basically though, bread is just flour mixed with a binding agent, so it could have just been wheat and water - after all, they were in a hurry.

Comment: What about the bread and the wine that Jehovah Witness use today?

Comment: Not being a member, I can only make assumptions. If you want specifically their take on it, you might want to add a tag for that, such as "jehovahs-witnesses" If they hold true to the original though, I can at least say that they won't use any leavening, such as yeast.

Comment: Well I was referring to the bread and wine used in a modern communion feast.

Comment: Almost always wheat and almost always grape (whether wine or juice). Some denominations have very specific rules while others have hardly none. For JW's I don't know specifically what they say about this. *To close voters*, it is clear that this is asking for the JW answer to this.

Comment: @fredsbend Thank you! Yes I would like to be educated on right ingredients of the *The LORD's Evening Meal (Emblems?)| JW*

Comment: @Flimzy I think it is pretty clear it is asking for JW perspective.

Comment: Comment by @Sara: "What about the bread and the wine that Jehovah Witness use today?"

Comment: Wait till nisan 14 and attend their only celebrated event. That's where it is consumed. I'm sure someone would show you the package they come from as it is highly unlikely they bake it themselves. After all, their intention is not to be secretive. For all they know you have food allergies and you just want to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

To find a proper answer to this good question, have a look at [their 12/15 2013 Watchtower magazine](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2013926). The paragraphs 5-7, under the subtitle 'The Emblems' should interest you.

As a summary, **the bread** was made from wheat flour and water, without any leaven or seasoning, such as salt, being added. Because it was unleavened, it would not have risen.

[UPDATE] They recently edited a video on how to make the bread : [How to Make Memorial Bread](https://www.jw.org/en/library/videos/#en/mediaitems/MeetingsConventions/pub-jwbrd_201603_2_VIDEO)

**For the wine**, as there was no need for augmenting or fortifying the value of Jesus’ blood, the wine used is not a type fortified with brandy or spices. Plain red wine should be used, a homemade wine or a commercial wine, such as Beaujolais, Burgundy, or Chianti.

Comment: Excellent! I believe great example on how to answer questions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

E 1. 240 grams of flour

2. 60 ml of water
3. Mix untill the dough does not stick on the wall of the (glass) potter.
4. Take the dough on the table and with a bit dried flour mix it about 5 min.
5. Separate the dough in 2 pieces and make them into round balls and then stretch them like round plates of about 3 mm.
6. Put the dough plate in a slightly oiled Pan and perforate some holes with a fork.
7. Place the Pan in a preheated oven with 230 Celsius for about 8 Minutes.

Watch this video: [How to Make Memorial Bread](https://www.jw.org/finder?srcid=share&prefer=content&applanguage=E&locale=en&item=pub-jwbrd_201603_2_VIDEO&docid=1011214).

Comment: I take it the flour to be used must be plain flour, and not self-raising flour.

Answer (score 1):

We always mix wheat flour and water and fry it in a pan. The wine is what would have been available to them in Egypt, just a red grape wine, unadulterated thus reflecting the purity of Jesus' sacrifice.

Comment: Are you a JW? If so, is there some JW manual on how to make it or did you get your recipe from parents/family?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as store-bought kosher flatbread and simple grape-based wine. The emphasis is on unleavened bread and the wine being a decent comparison to what was drank at the passover.

Comment: Any supporting references?